# Changing language from hardware keyboard in ASUS Eee Pad Transformer TF300T

Tags: keyboard, asus-eee-pad-transformer, 4.1-jelly-bean

Today I have updated my *Asus Eee Pad Transformer TF300T* to Android 4.1 and was very disappointed. On Android 4.0 I used Ctrl+Space in *Russian ASUS Keyboard* to switch input language between English and Russian, and now it's not working! Just pop up notice that language was changed but language stays Russian. I've tried to use other languages, but all of them do the same. Restarting device does not help.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> does the job. A window appears where you can change the language. Worse than in Windows, but still...

Comment: Might help to include screenshot of this?